# OS X Notify When Apps Open, Quit, and Change Focus

Tags: macos, cocoa, window

Is there any way for a cocoa application to be notified when other applications open or quit, or when different windows (of either the listening app or others) are brought to the forefront?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an observer to the shared workspaces notificationCenter:

```
[[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserverForName:NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
    NSRunningApplication *frontmostApplication = [[note userInfo] objectForKey:NSWorkspaceApplicationKey];
}];

// from NSWorkspace.h
APPKIT_EXTERN NSString * NSWorkspaceWillLaunchApplicationNotification;  //  see above
APPKIT_EXTERN NSString * NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification;   //  see above
APPKIT_EXTERN NSString * NSWorkspaceDidTerminateApplicationNotification;    //  see above
APPKIT_EXTERN NSString * const NSWorkspaceDidHideApplicationNotification NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_6);
APPKIT_EXTERN NSString * const NSWorkspaceDidUnhideApplicationNotification NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_6);
APPKIT_EXTERN NSString * const NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_6);
APPKIT_EXTERN NSString * const NSWorkspaceDidDeactivateApplicationNotification NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_6);
```

Comment: Oh and remember removing the observer upon deallocation!